# sp_blitzindex Index Evaluation Results

Tags: sql-server, index, performance, sp-blitzindex, performance-tuning

Need some help with the results from the sp_blitzindex. Below is one of the suggestion but not able to understand the comment.

http://BrentOzar.com/go/AbnormalPsychology

> dbo.ACCT_RECV_ADDRESS has 18 out of 20 columns in one or more
>   publications.

Could anyone clarify what does it mean..? Does table participating in replication has any effect on indexes..?

Answer (score 2):

That one is just an FYI and not something that you should take action on. Some of the rows returned will be FYI-type things, some will be things that you should look into more, some will be things that you should take action on. Like I ignore the "addicted to strings" and "addicted to nulls" rows. Those are just FYIs. I take action on the missing indexes section, though not all of them, depends on the details.